# How much technology does Oz have in Emerald City?

Tags: emerald-city

In the show Emerald City we see many pieces of modern technology in Oz: lightbulbs, electric saws, flying monkey drones, etc.  And yet we also see people traveling on horseback with swords.  And Dorothy's gun seems like some incredible magic to the people of Oz.

So is there any coherent explanation for the state of technology in Oz?  How have they developed electricity and drones without inventing the automobile or gunpowder?

Is it an issue of the cities having advanced technology, whereas the rural areas have medieval technology?  That's what it seems like based on the episodes that have aired so far.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be explained by the basic storyline that the "Wizard" wasn't actually from Oz in the first place? Perhaps the engineering marvels are a result of the characters abilities who traveled with him - some things were doable, some things not, given rather limited resources to begin with...

Comment: I don't think the show ever discloses it since it was canceled after only one season, but this answer seems the most plausible having an inventor "here" or "there" in conjunction to Oz's metaphysics makes sense as to how it would be so random Not to say that it also doesn't apply to class system, but I think that's secondary to the "how" of it.